# Google Merchant Center : Content API - How to add product to datafeed of input type local product

Tags: php, google-api, google-shopping-api, google-content-api, google-merchant-center

I am using php, I have created datafeed using content API which is of contentType "local products".

```
$apiUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/content/v2.1/[Merchant_Id]/datafeeds?access_token=".[API_token];
$request = array(
   "contentType"=>"local products",
       "fileName"=>"local_datafeedfile",
       "name"=>"Local Datafeed",
       "targets"=>array(
          array(
           "country"=>"IN",
           "language"=>"EN"
          )
       )
   );
```

Now I need to add products to this datafeed.
I am using this api to add product

```
https://www.googleapis.com/content/v2.1/[Merchant_Id]/products?feedId=[Feed_id]&access_token=".[API_token];
```

The problem is the [Feed_id]  which always show **[feedId] Invalid feed id: xxxxxxxx**
I am using the same id for feed_id generated on adding local product datafeed from above request

Comment: You made a typo, you missed `&`  after the `[Feed_id]`. Correct url `https://www.googleapis.com/content/v2.1/[Merchant_Id]/products?feedId=[Feed_id]&access_token=".[API_token];`
This question must be closed, as the solutions are code specific.

Comment: @krylov123 No, that is not the issue, I did it while posting this question I have to remove the actual ids to maintain privacy in doing do by mistake & was removed.
But the issue still remains the same

Comment: Then provide the actual code you use. Because what you show is not a valid php code, so we could'nt reproduce it. Help others help you.